# How to add text Stamp annotation in a rotation pdf

Tags: rotation, annotations, stamp

I want to add stamp annotation with text into a pdf.
The rotation of the pdf is 270.

The code I wrote, but the stamp rotation is wrong.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath(), "PDF".getBytes());
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
int i = 1;
PdfContentByte content = stamper.getOverContent(i);
Rectangle pageRect = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i);
float pageWidth = pageRect.getWidth();
float pageHeight = pageRect.getHeight();
float rectWidth = 700;
float rectHeight = 500;
float fontsize = 40;
content.setFontAndSize(font, fontsize);
rectWidth = content.getEffectiveStringWidth(stampLabel,false);
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,rectWidth, rectHeight);
PdfAppearance appearance = content.createAppearance(rectWidth,rectHeight);
appearance.setColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
appearance.setFontAndSize(font, fontsize);      
rectangle.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
rectangle.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
rectangle.setBorderWidth(2);
appearance.rectangle(rectangle);
appearance.saveState();
appearance.beginText();
appearance.showText(stampLabel);
appearance.restoreState();
PdfAnnotation stampAnnot =   PdfAnnotation.createStamp(content.getPdfWriter(),    rectangle,stampLabel,"STATUA_STAMP");
stampAnnot.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, appearance);
stampAnnot.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);         
stamper.addAnnotation(stampAnnot, i);
```